# webscraping returning backend data only

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I built this code to **scrape** TSX website key data:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Brave Chrome/92.0.4515.131 Safari/537.36'
    }

url = "https://money.tmx.com/en/quote/EIT.UN"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

But I get an extract that doesn't contain anything from the page:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en">
>  <head>
>   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
>   <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
>   <meta content="#000000" name="theme-color"/>
>   <link href="/favicon.ico" rel="icon"/>
>   <link href="/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180"/>
>   <link href="/favicon-32x32.png" rel="icon" sizes="32x32" type="image/png"/>
>   <link href="/favicon-16x16.png" rel="icon" sizes="16x16" type="image/png"/>
>   <link color="#5bbad5" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" rel="mask-icon"/>
>   <link href="/manifest.json" rel="manifest"/>
>   <meta content="#1e222b" name="msapplication-TileColor"/>
>   <meta content="#ffffff" name="theme-color"/>
>   <title>
>    TMX Money
>   </title>
>   <link href="https://unpkg.com/normalize.css@8.0.1/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
>   <script async="" src="//tags-cdn.deployads.com/a/tmx.com.js">
>   </script>
>   <link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/fonts/DINPro_Regular.woff2" rel="preload" type="font/woff2"/>
>   <link as="font" crossorigin="" href="/fonts/DINPro_Medium.woff2" rel="preload" type="font/woff2"/>
>   <meta content="oxLF6WU3pPwwIFLyZVG13lWRJMcqvfYNAX1IOvQiUPI" name="google-site-verification"/>
>   <script>
>    window.onpageshow=function(o){o.persisted&&window.location.reload()}
>   </script>
>   <script>
>    "undefined"!=typeof navigator&&(navigator.userAgent.includes("Prerender")||navigator.userAgent.includes("prerender"))&&(SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY=!0)
>   </script>
>   <link href="/static/css/45.0b0c574e.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
>  </head>
>  <body>
>   <noscript>
>    You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
>   </noscript>
>   <div id="root">
>   </div>
>   <div id="modal-root">
>   </div>
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>    piAId="564512",piCId="20383",piHostname="pi.pardot.com",function(){function t(){var
> ```
>
> t=document.createElement("script");t.type="text/javascript",t.src=("https:"==document.location.protocol?"https://pi":"http://cdn")+".pardot.com/pd.js";var
> e=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];e.parentNode.insertBefore(t,e)}window.attachEvent?window.attachEvent("onload",t):window.addEventListener("load",t,!1)}()
>
>
> !function(e){function a(a){for(var c,r,d=a[0],o=a[1],i=a[2],p=0,u=[];p<d.length;p++)r=d[p],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,r)&&n[r]&&u.push(n[r][0]),n[r]=0;for(c
> in
> o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,c)&&(e[c]=o[c]);for(s&&s(a);u.length;)u.shift()();return
> f.push.apply(f,i||[]),t()}function t(){for(var
> e,a=0;a<f.length;a++){for(var t=f[a],c=!0,r=1;r<t.length;r++){var
> o=t[r];0!==n[o]&&(c=!1)}c&&(f.splice(a--,1),e=d(d.s=t[0]))}return
> e}var c={},r={44:0},n={44:0},f=[];function d(a){if(c[a])return
> c[a].exports;var t=c[a]={i:a,l:!1,exports:{}};return
> e[a].call(t.exports,t,t.exports,d),t.l=!0,t.exports}d.e=function(e){var
> a=[];r[e]?a.push(r[e]):0!==r[e]&&{0:1,1:1,4:1,15:1,39:1,46:1}[e]&&a.push(r[e]=new
> Promise((function(a,t){for(var
> c="static/css/"+({18:"footer",19:"header",21:"page.admincompanycontent",22:"page.admindashboard",23:"page.admininfo",24:"page.advancedchart",25:"page.alerts",26:"page.authcallback",27:"page.devpanel",28:"page.etfcentre",29:"page.etfcomparison",30:"page.home",31:"page.marketssummary",32:"page.notfound",33:"page.quote",34:"page.search",35:"page.settings",36:"page.signin",37:"page.stocklist",38:"page.stocklists",39:"page.stockscreener",40:"page.terms",41:"page.tsx302021",42:"page.verifyemail",43:"page.watchlist"}[e]||e)+"."+{0:"c46f6ca1",1:"d488a845",2:"31d6cfe0",3:"31d6cfe0",4:"e69ef5e8",5:"31d6cfe0",6:"31d6cfe0",7:"31d6cfe0",8:"31d6cfe0",9:"31d6cfe0",10:"31d6cfe0",11:"31d6cfe0",12:"31d6cfe0",13:"31d6cfe0",14:"31d6cfe0",15:"d34d0f8b",16:"31d6cfe0",17:"31d6cfe0",18:"31d6cfe0",19:"31d6cfe0",21:"31d6cfe0",22:"31d6cfe0",23:"31d6cfe0",24:"31d6cfe0",25:"31d6cfe0",26:"31d6cfe0",27:"31d6cfe0",28:"31d6cfe0",29:"31d6cfe0",30:"31d6cfe0",31:"31d6cfe0",32:"31d6cfe0",33:"31d6cfe0",34:"31d6cfe0",35:"31d6cfe0",36:"31d6cfe0",37:"31d6cfe0",38:"31d6cfe0",39:"5cf87ee8",40:"31d6cfe0",41:"31d6cfe0",42:"31d6cfe0",43:"31d6cfe0",46:"94d2147f",47:"31d6cfe0",48:"31d6cfe0",49:"31d6cfe0",50:"31d6cfe0",51:"31d6cfe0",52:"31d6cfe0",53:"31d6cfe0",54:"31d6cfe0",55:"31d6cfe0",56:"31d6cfe0",57:"31d6cfe0",58:"31d6cfe0",59:"31d6cfe0",60:"31d6cfe0",61:"31d6cfe0",62:"31d6cfe0",63:"31d6cfe0",64:"31d6cfe0",65:"31d6cfe0",66:"31d6cfe0",67:"31d6cfe0"}[e]+".chunk.css",n=d.p+c,f=document.getElementsByTagName("link"),o=0;o<f.length;o++){var i=(s=f[o]).getAttribute("data-href")||s.getAttribute("href");if("stylesheet"===s.rel&&(i===c||i===n))return
> a()}var
> p=document.getElementsByTagName("style");for(o=0;o<p.length;o++){var
> s;if((i=(s=p[o]).getAttribute("data-href"))===c||i===n)return a()}var
> u=document.createElement("link");u.rel="stylesheet",u.type="text/css",u.onload=a,u.onerror=function(a){var
> c=a&&a.target&&a.target.src||n,f=new Error("Loading CSS chunk "+e+"
> failed.\n("+c+")");f.code="CSS_CHUNK_LOAD_FAILED",f.request=c,delete
> r[e],u.parentNode.removeChild(u),t(f)},u.href=n,document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(u)})).then((function(){r[e]=0})));var
> t=n[e];if(0!==t)if(t)a.push(t[2]);else{var c=new
> Promise((function(a,c){t=n[e]=[a,c]}));a.push(t[2]=c);var
> f,o=document.createElement("script");o.charset="utf-8",o.timeout=120,d.nc&&o.setAttribute("nonce",d.nc),o.src=function(e){return
> d.p+"static/js/"+({18:"footer",19:"header",21:"page.admincompanycontent",22:"page.admindashboard",23:"page.admininfo",24:"page.advancedchart",25:"page.alerts",26:"page.authcallback",27:"page.devpanel",28:"page.etfcentre",29:"page.etfcomparison",30:"page.home",31:"page.marketssummary",32:"page.notfound",33:"page.quote",34:"page.search",35:"page.settings",36:"page.signin",37:"page.stocklist",38:"page.stocklists",39:"page.stockscreener",40:"page.terms",41:"page.tsx302021",42:"page.verifyemail",43:"page.watchlist"}[e]||e)+"."+{0:"3bf886dc",1:"36a077ef",2:"304b93f2",3:"aad23197",4:"b347aa4d",5:"8d07c059",6:"1a942e20",7:"3eace955",8:"684593b3",9:"a59fae53",10:"c86ddf7c",11:"c15a76a9",12:"2ebc2b8d",13:"5a9662c3",14:"98c1b9e7",15:"71ab84f5",16:"ab482800",17:"a0a7a872",18:"c1361d6f",19:"695f2560",21:"30610631",22:"88cd3df4",23:"02e7e23f",24:"7ac96b36",25:"b46712a8",26:"defeb6a3",27:"ea288e40",28:"1f2df7fa",29:"31f26ed5",30:"c025e5e2",31:"d6d116eb",32:"c1a96e84",33:"e61043f0",34:"53152b1c",35:"98c1f6a3",36:"f03094c0",37:"2d009271",38:"cf9680f3",39:"7101ddac",40:"0b15da7e",41:"91471a80",42:"f1ae28a6",43:"1a5a65d3",46:"4d4b1467",47:"8543c258",48:"7e804703",49:"b62fad4b",50:"dce0e3cb",51:"0ec82fe9",52:"9329bc73",53:"4279abc7",54:"93ee9948",55:"fcaa0f53",56:"7e64f2a0",57:"198998df",58:"b836b3c6",59:"7ef7187c",60:"b84c7ab4",61:"9f4229fa",62:"926a402c",63:"bc502904",64:"944dd1ae",65:"cdf5fd44",66:"fe991ddf",67:"8a557aa7"}[e]+".chunk.js"}(e);var
> i=new Error;f=function(a){o.onerror=o.onload=null,clearTimeout(p);var
> t=n[e];if(0!==t){if(t){var
> c=a&&("load"===a.type?"missing":a.type),r=a&&a.target&&a.target.src;i.message="Loading
> chunk "+e+" failed.\n("+c+":
> "+r+")",i.name="ChunkLoadError",i.type=c,i.request=r,t1}n[e]=void
> 0}};var
> p=setTimeout((function(){f({type:"timeout",target:o})}),12e4);o.onerror=o.onload=f,document.head.appendChild(o)}return
> Promise.all(a)},d.m=e,d.c=c,d.d=function(e,a,t){d.o(e,a)||Object.defineProperty(e,a,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},d.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof
> Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},d.t=function(e,a){if(1&a&&(e=d(e)),8&a)return e;if(4&a&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var
> t=Object.create(null);if(d.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&a&&"string"!=typeof
> e)for(var c in e)d.d(t,c,function(a){return e[a]}.bind(null,c));return
> t},d.n=function(e){var a=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return
> e.default}:function(){return e};return
> d.d(a,"a",a),a},d.o=function(e,a){return
> Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,a)},d.p="/",d.oe=function(e){throw
> console.error(e),e};var
> o=this["webpackJsonptmx-money-client"]=this["webpackJsonptmx-money-client"]||[],i=o.push.bind(o);o.push=a,o=o.slice();for(var
> p=0;p<o.length;p++)a(o[p]);var s=i;t()}([])

Is there a security in place blocking the web scraping or am I writing the code the wrong way?

Comment: “*I get an extract that doesn't contain anything from the page*” This output you’ve provided matches the target page source exactly. What specifically do you believe is missing that should be included? Is that information loaded via JavaScript? If so, can you point to a line or lines in your script that you believe should return the page’s content after evaluating JavaScript?

Comment: @esqew , for example I want to get the open price metrics and dividends tables data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually data is generating from api calls json response. If you make disable javascript then you will see that the page goes blank meaning the url is dynamic. That's why we can't get data thus way. Here is the working example:

Code:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json
op=[]
so=[]

body = {"operationName":"getQuoteBySymbol","variables":{"symbol":"EIT.UN","locale":"en"},"query":"query getQuoteBySymbol($symbol: String, $locale: String) {\n  getQuoteBySymbol(symbol: $symbol, locale: $locale) {\n    symbol\n    name\n    price\n    priceChange\n    percentChange\n    exchangeName\n    exShortName\n    exchangeCode\n    marketPlace\n    sector\n    industry\n    volume\n    openPrice\n    dayHigh\n    dayLow\n    MarketCap\n    MarketCapAllClasses\n    peRatio\n    prevClose\n    dividendFrequency\n    dividendYield\n    dividendAmount\n    dividendCurrency\n    beta\n    eps\n    exDividendDate\n    shortDescription\n    longDescription\n    website\n    email\n    phoneNumber\n    fullAddress\n    employees\n    shareOutStanding\n    totalDebtToEquity\n    totalSharesOutStanding\n    sharesESCROW\n    vwap\n    dividendPayDate\n    weeks52high\n    weeks52low\n    alpha\n    averageVolume10D\n    averageVolume30D\n    averageVolume50D\n    priceToBook\n    priceToCashFlow\n    returnOnEquity\n    returnOnAssets\n    day21MovingAvg\n    day50MovingAvg\n    day200MovingAvg\n    dividend3Years\n    dividend5Years\n    datatype\n    issueType\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
headers = {
    
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8,es;q=0.7,ar;q=0.6",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "content-length": "1197",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "locale": "en",
    "origin": "https://money.tmx.com",
    "pragma": "no-cache",
    "referer": "https://money.tmx.com/",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-site",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36"
    }


url = "https://app-money.tmx.com/graphql"

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
resp = r.json()['data']['getQuoteBySymbol']


op.append(resp['openPrice']),
so.append(resp['totalSharesOutStanding'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'Open_price':op,'Listed Shares Outstanding': so})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
Open_price  Listed Shares Outstanding
  12.45                  135671000
```

Comment: OMG! It works! I had this issue for weeks as Yahoo Finance degraded their API output and I was left with missing information... Thank you so much!!